# I can't perform science experiments but retrieving space crafts

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I have gone into space and went EVA and right clicked on my kerbal, nothing appeared. (I am in science mode) I can't use the mystery goo container or science jr. I am on a mac and using 1.0.4.

Comment: Are you right clicking your Mystery Goo and Science Jr modules while on EVA or while in the ship?  You need to be *really* close to it to use a module while on EVA.

Comment: When you started the game, did you maybe start a "sandbox" game, not a "career" game?

Comment: i started a science gamemode not career or sandbox and i can't use any science instruments at all in EVA or normal modes

Comment: This seems like a bug, although the bugtracker doesn't indicate any similar bug. I would try to debug it by first reinstalling the game, and then by doing a new -sandbox- game with just a Mk1 Command Pod. By right-clicking the manned capsule at the lauchpad, you should be able to perform some crew reports, which would mean you had some missing files.

Comment: Also, and this might sound silly but, how are you right-clicking? Checking up on it revealed that either you would do ctrl+click (which might interfere with throttle) or use two fingers. This reference to [KSP forums](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/38439-How-to-right-click-on-a-Mac-in-KSP) might help.

Comment: normal 1 finger right click

Comment: As the ships got bigger and gravity lag increases, rightclick often doesn't register. Sometimes I have to click a module 5-6 times before the context window appears.

Answer (score 2):

The only time you want to EVA regarding science experiments (aside from the obvious crew reports/surface samples/flags/etc) is to collect data for storage. With a kerbal in the command pod, right click on your thermometer, pressure sensor, etc., and run the experiments. You can either transmit them from there, or if you want to keep the data (usually for a higher science return) you can then EVA to collect the data, which requires proximity to the experiment item. Once you get close enough to the Science Jr., for example, you can right click and  "Collect Data", then go back near the command module and right click on it to store the data. This allows your command module to hold data from the same experiment in different biomes for example, increasing your overall science output.

A scientist also has to reset certain experiments (like the Science Jr and Mystery Goo canisters) in order for them to be used again. That also requires an EVA, but can be done immediately after collecting the data from that experiment.

**tl;dr**: Don't EVA to perform the experiments, just run the experiments with the kerbal in the command module, then you can EVA to collect the data and/or reset the experiments.

Comment: i can't do the experiments so that comment is useless

Comment: You're trying to perform them while on EVA though?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question but it is phrased poorly.

In my KSP saves, I cannot be in EVA in order to use scientific instruments on the spacecraft (the Mystery Goo and Science Junior are both spacecraft items, and thus can only be controlled when you are playing as THAT spacecraft only.)

You can use EVA to perform scientific experiments on the surface of a planet (gathering samples). For this you right-click your Kerbal and select "Collect Samples" (or something on those lines.)

If you want a crew report, right click on the cockpit of your craft and select "Crew Report". This gives a moderate amount of science.

Every time you repeat a scientific experiment, it gives less science (lets say you are on the Kerbin coast playing with Mystery Goo and it gives you 8 science the first time, it will give you 2 the next, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried that but it doesn't work i cannot right click on mystery goo or science jr. i cannot do sample or crew report when i right click on the pod

Comment: @reaper0203 are you able to see the selection, but unable to carry it out? Or are you able to carry out the action and it gives you +0.0 science. Also, do you already have all the rocket and plane parts unlocked?

Comment: The part about not being able to run experiments outside the spacecraft is incorrect, as kerbal Scientists can do just that (but only them, though).

Comment: i am unabe to even start to carry out ANY experiments when i right click on the pod it gives me ell options BUT crew report and when i right click on science parts NOTHING happens

Comment: and i unlocked engineering 101 (i think that is what its called)